# Aligning text in a listbox

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

I have this code in a xaml page:

```
<ListBox Height="524" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,6,0,0" Name="listBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="438" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="White" >
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Margin="5" TextAlignment="Left" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding DeadLine}" Margin="5" TextAlignment="Right" HorizontalAlignment="Right" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

As you can see, I am dividing my listbox in 2 textboxes and trying to put one text in the left most position and the other one in the right most position in the line. But I can't, this doesn't work.
Am I missing something? How cn I put the deadline aligned right?

Thanks,
Oscar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just got a solution mixing many solutions I found (including given in this forum)

```
<ListBox Height="524" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,6,0,0" Name="listBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="438" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="White" >
            <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
                </Style>
            </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding DeadLine}" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

tks!

Comment: Just as an FYI, you need to make sure that your Name and Deadline text will never be long enough to have them overlap.  This markup actually causes the 2 `TextBlock` objects to occupy the same space, you just have one with Text aligned left and one with Text aligned right.

Comment: Yes, that is true, I have already noticed that, but thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that the `ItemContainerStyle` has `HorizontalContentAlignment` to Stretch.

This works for me:

```
<ListBox Height="524" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,6,0,0" Name="listBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="438" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="White" >
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Orientation="Horizontal" Background="Red">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Margin="5" TextAlignment="Left" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding DeadLine}" Margin="5" TextAlignment="Right" HorizontalAlignment="Right" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: I found out about the horizontalContentAlignment property, but It didn't worked. To be sure, I copied and pasted your code, still didn't work out :(